# Google Tracks geofencing & visualisation API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am developing a node.js application which (amongst other things) will recieve location information from remote users and allow them to interact with each other via the server.

I'm using the Google Tracks API because I like the idea of being able to track users when appropriate, set up geofencing to define my coverage areas and to visualise what's happening.

The Google tracks API documentation is reasonable, however I'm not sure how I would go about actually visualising the entities and geofencing I have setup on a map - this is not something that  I can find covered elsewhere.

Ideally I would be able to simply embed a map into a webpage which could link with my Tracks API account and show all of the fencing and entities.  Another nice feature would be the ability to 'draw' a geofence, is there anything out there which would allow this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Tracks API does not currently offer any kind of server-side rendering for your Tracks data, so the best approach is to use the API to retrieve the [crumbs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/crumbs#summarizing_an_entitys_path) (or just current location) and render them using [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) (or just markers) in the Google Maps API.  You can similarly get all your [geofences](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/geofences#requesting_a_contiguous_list_of_geofences) and render them using [polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple).

Because this is done clientside, you'll probably want to limit your data to a reasonable number (depending on the browser/OS combination, something like O(thousands) of vertices).

All this assumes that your app meets the terms of service of the Maps API so check those out as well.